# Upload de arquivos usando REST e Java

Tags: java, ajax, rest, upload, restful

Estou criando uma aplicação e preciso de uma forma de fazer upload de arquivos xls/xlsx, enviando o arquivo do front-end (Ajax) para o back-end (Java) para que possa ser manipulado.

Código Ajax:

```
$("#formulario").submit(function () {
                var formData = new FormData(this);

                $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
                        alert('sucesso');
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert('deu erro');
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    xhr: function() {  
                        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if (myXhr.upload) { 
                            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function () {

                                alert('upando o arquivo');
                            }, false);
                        }
                    return myXhr;
                    }
                });
            });
```

O Código Ajax esta funcionando perfeitamente, ele executa e me retorna o código 200. Porém não consigo 'receber' o arquivo no Java.

Código Java:

```
@POST
@Path("/upload")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response create(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm input){
    System.out.println("funcionou");
    //manipulo o arquivo
    return Response.ok;
}
```

Espero que conseguem me auxiliar e orientar a fazer funcionar.

**UPDATE**

Fiz uma alteração no ajax, e enfim, consegui fazer com que o JAVA receba a requisição

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var form;
                $('#fileUpload').change(function (event) {
                    form = new FormData();
                    form.append('fileUpload', event.target.files[0]); // para apenas 1 arquivo
                    //var name = event.target.files[0].content.name; // para capturar o nome do arquivo com sua extenção
                });

                $('#btnEnviar').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/SferaCR/rest/importacao', // Url do lado server que vai receber o arquivo
                        data: form,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('sucesso');
                            $('#fileUpload').val('');
                        },
                        error: function (){
                            alert('deu erro');
                            $('#fileUpload').val('');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Porem, o problema agora, é que no java, que está recebendo o parametro 'input' como null. Ou seja, a requisição vai, da 'certo', mas o arquivo não é enviado.

Comment: de onde está a vir a variável `url` no seu código javascript e o que contém dentro dela?

Comment: Que implementação da JAX-RS você está usando?

Comment: Minha sugestão é que você procure a documentação do `FileUploadForm` que está usando. Muito provavelmente é alguma biblioteca que trabalha com ´Buffers...´ ou bytearrays. Em qualquer uma das opções é bem simples converter em um arquivo e salvar em algum lugar no seu server.

Comment: @CIRCLE contem o json (ou xml), que retorna os dados do REST.

Comment: @Luídne não estou usando nenhuma implementação JAX-RS. Você recomenda o uso da mesma?

Comment: @JorgeCampos valeu pela ajuda, vou dar uma verificada se ela trabalha assim. Mas mesmo se isso acontecesse e eu tivesse algum erro ai, não teria uma exception no java? Porque nada acontece.

Comment: @EricoSouza o que você quer dizer é que não está imprimindo o "funcionou". Caso sim, não foi isso que tinha entendido. Se este for o caso, o que está sendo passado no parâmetro `url` da função ajax?

Comment: @JorgeCampos não é que ele não está imprimindo não funcionou. O problema é que o meu ajax, envia  arquivo do upload. Mas o java 'não recebe'. Algo assim.

Comment: Como está sua tag form no seu html/jsp, a do formulário com id 'formulario'?

Comment: @JorgeCampos segue abaixo:
`
<form id="formulario" method="post" name="fileupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="arquivo" type="file" />
    <button>Enviar</button>
</form>`

Comment: A url, eu estou usando um rest (json/xml), que usei em outros modelos com envio de formularios e ok. Mas para upload de arquivos, consigo usar o mesmo?

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Comment: @EricoSouza achou alguma solução?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma alteração no ajax, e enfim, consegui fazer com que o JAVA receba a requisição

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var form;
                $('#fileUpload').change(function (event) {
                    form = new FormData();
                    form.append('fileUpload', event.target.files[0]); // para apenas 1 arquivo
                    //var name = event.target.files[0].content.name; // para capturar o nome do arquivo com sua extenção
                });

                $('#btnEnviar').click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:8080/SferaCR/rest/importacao', // Url do lado server que vai receber o arquivo
                        data: form,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('sucesso');
                            $('#fileUpload').val('');
                        },
                        error: function (){
                            alert('deu erro');
                            $('#fileUpload').val('');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

Porem, para funcionar corretamente foi necessário retirar a `Annotation` `@Path`, da minha *action* que recebia a requisição do ajax.